Use Spring or other to avoid lasagna (layered) code
Imagine the following classes
public abstract class BasePage {
    // Common functionality for all pages
}

public class LoginPage extends BasePage {
    public void login(String username, String password) {
        // login logic
    }
}

public class HomePage extends BasePage {
    public void goToHome() {
        // navigate to home logic
    }
}

Would be possible to create User.java and expose somehow some methods from injected dependencies? (Some pseudocode to showcase)
public class User {

    @Resource LoginPage loginPage;
    @Resource HomePage homePage;

    // want to avoid
    /*public void login(String username, String password) {
        loginPage.login(username, password);
    }*/

    // somehow expose loginPage.login() - avoiding Java Reflection or verbose solutions

}


After initiate user, I can do user.login().

If you use interfaces then you can add default methods.
public interface BasePage {
    // Common functionality for all pages
}

public interface LoginPage extends BasePage {
    public default void login(String username, String password) {
        // login logic
    }
}

public interface HomePage extends BasePage {
    public default void goToHome() {
        // navigate to home logic
    }
}

public class User implements LoginPage, HomePage {

}


That became available since 8, 11, 17 ?

@PauloOliveira Default methods were added with Java 8. Third bullet point, What's New in JDK 8.
